# Playing wavs with alsa. Determing number of frames?

Tags: c++, wav, alsa

I'm trying to play a wav in alsa and failing. It plays but either its too short and cuts playing early or too big and segfaults... All depending on last parameter of that function on line 81.
http://paste2.org/p/2708324#line-81

Comment: Did you debug it to locate the segfault? Sounds like undefined behavior...

Comment: segfault is expected when I set frames > length of buffer.

Comment: I hate ALSA and I'm sorry you have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your wav file is formatted as your code is expecting it?  Your wavHeader struct is making a number of assumptions about the wav file being played -- it will not work with all wav files (certainly not with the ones I tried it with).  It's entirely possible that when you are reading Subchunk2Size, that you're getting an incorrect value.  Your code will only work for a very specific variation of the wav file format.